# How to start developing a web app to store data to CosmosDB in Azure

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-cosmosdb

How do I get started the best way if I want to develop a quite simple web application that will store some user data into an Azure CosmosDB.

The web application should contain user authorization and everything should run in Azure. Furthermore I am pretty good in PHP and C#, which I prefer as development language.

**My Question:** Can any of you point me to a good tutorial or LinkedIn-Learning-Course?
I would prefer using Visual Studio Code as my primary environment.

Comment: Take a look. You can start with this. Good luck for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are trying to develop a web application using CosmosDB which can be run on azure portal.

Here is the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-dotnet) you could learn step by step.

If you need code sample you [can check here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/tree/master/samples/code-samples).

You can also find this [sample for CRUD](https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2017/08/17/getting-started-azure-cosmos-db-part-1-crud/) operation.

**Note:** I would suggest you to finish [each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-dotnet) of the document from beginning to end. So that later on you can easily grab other tutorials.